# Android Studio: getting a Parsing error and can't find the issue

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing

I have a JSONArray with a format like this:

```
[
{
"type": "fuel",
"name": "Esso",
"address": "Frankfurter Straße 65",
"lat": 49.8848387,
"lon": 8.6520691 },
{
"type": "amenity",
"name": "Hauptbahnhof",
"address": "Am Hauptbahnhof 20",
"lat": 49.8725, 
"lon": 8.628889,
"icon": "bahnhof.jpg" }
]
```

and it goes on.

the moment I open the activity where I want my JSONArray to be in a Listview I get a Toast with the Message of my catchblock "error parsing: .." and it shows me the whole JSONFile in the toast.

Can someone explain me why this is happening, I can't find my mistake. I'll show you guys my Tryblock where the error gets catched.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url = "...excluded link...";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String type = c.getString("type");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String lat = c.getString("lat");
                    String lon = c.getString("lon");
                    String icon = c.getString("icon");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("type", type);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("address", address );
                    contact.put("lat", lat);
                    contact.put("lon", lon);
                    contact.put("icon", icon);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: this is the JSON which you have posted you want to parse?
if yes then you ae not parsing it correctly. in your first object there is no "icon". so you have to either make sure that icon is there in the object or check if the key-value exists.

Comment: Hello Ashwani, yes this is the JSON I want to parse. There are blocks with an icon and blocks without an icon. Could you explain me how I could exactly check for the key value? I never worked with JSON before and it's quite overwhelming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is correct it looks like:

```
 {
  "contacts": [
    {
      "type": "fuel",
      "name": "Esso",
      "address": "Frankfurter Straße 65",
      "lat": 49.8848387,
      "lon": 8.6520691
    },
    {
      "type": "amenity",
      "name": "Hauptbahnhof",
      "address": "Am Hauptbahnhof 20",
      "lat": 49.8725,
      "lon": 8.628889,
      "icon": "bahnhof.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

now how to parse it using CHECK for KEY look at the code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

// Getting JSON Array node
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

// looping through All Contacts
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    String type = c.getString("type");
    String name = c.getString("name");
    String address = c.getString("address");
    String lat = c.getString("lat");
    String lon = c.getString("lon");
    String icon;
    if(c.has("icon")){
        //your json is having "icon" Key, get the value
        icon = c.getString("icon");
    }
    else{
        //your json is NOT having "icon" Key,  assign a dummy value 
        icon = "/default/icon_url(if_any)";
    }
}
```

this will do, it will assign a default url of icon if any or any other string that you want to store in case icon is not present or you can leave it empty, and if icon exists, you will get the url.
you can ask for any doubts related to this answer.

Happy coding..:)